# OctoberCMS: Possible bug with commands. Error: "Call to a member function writeln() on null"

Tags: php, laravel, shell, command, octobercms

I use build 419, this is a simple example for explain the problem. I have this class A:

```
class A extends Command
{
   protected $name = 'projects:a';

   public function fire()
   {
      $this->a();
   }

   public function a()
   {
      $this->info('Hello');
   }
}
```

I would like to call from class B the method a():

```
class B extends Command
{
   protected $name = 'projects:b';

   public function fire()
   {

      $a = new A();
      $a->a();

   }
}
```

But when I run the command "`php artisan projects:b`" this is the console error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>   Call to a member function writeln() on null

Both commands are correctly registered in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to access that method as well you need output.

If the case is that you just want to execute some code you can remove or comment that

```
 // $this->info('Hello');
```

and your console command should run as expected.

in this case when **$this->info('Hello')** is called and its try to write output in output buffer .. but its not able to find it.

if you want to define output buffer so this **info** method content can be received by output. you need to run command with output buffer **make sure this will execute other whole command**

```
use App;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

// .....

$command = App::make('Author\Testplugin\Console\CommandA');
$command->setLaravel($this->laravel);
$input = new ArrayInput([]);
$output = new BufferedOutput();
$resultCode = $command->run($input, $output);

// your method
$command->oks();

$content = $output->fetch(); // output of another command

$this->output->writeln('Hello world! B');
$this->output->writeln($content);
```

if you just need part of logic nothing more you just remove that **info method** and you are good to go.

```
$command = App::make('Author\Testplugin\Console\CommandA');
$command->setLaravel($this->laravel);
$command->a();
```